# Split out props.location.search value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-props

I'm trying to split out the values from props.location.search in React/Redux. I've successfully obtained the mixOne split however I can't seem to return the value of quantity. Here's my code:

```
  const mixOne = props.location.search
    ? String(props.location.search.split("mixOne=")[1])
    : "None";
  const quantity = props.location.search
    ? Number(props.location.search.split("=")[1])
    : 1;
```

And here's the URL that gets generated:

```
  const addToCartHandler = () => {
    props.history.push(
      `/Cart/${productId}?quantity=${quantity}?mixOne=${mixOne}`
    );
  };
```

[image: query]

As you can see quantity returns null, when I need the value selected

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`props.location.search.split("=")` on `"?quantity=1?mixOne=Grape"` would return `[ '?quantity', '1?mixOne', 'Grape' ]` since the next `=` is not until after `mixOne`.

There's a few different fixes here.

1. Your query string is invalid– a `?` denotes the start of the query string. Separate parameters should be split up using `&` ampersand characters. It should look like this: `?quantity=1&mixOne=Grape`
2. If you follow the standard here, you can then split it two ways: by `=` and then by `&` to get the different parameters. However, there is an easier way.
3. Using the new-ish [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) API, you can parse your parameters in a predictable way:

```
// Use the constructor with your `props.location.search` 
const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search);
// Use the getters to grab a specific value
const quantity = queryParams.get("quantity");
// Ensure it's a number for safety
const quantityNum = Number(quantity);

// ... the rest of your code here
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Using the 3rd option seemed to do the trick and the correct params are being returned :)

Answer (score 0):

The query is wrong. You're using double question marks. The second ? should be replaced with &.

`?quantity=1&mixOne=Grape`